# I have updated Laravel 5.7 to Laravel 8 and now have problem with email verification

Tags: php, laravel

I have updated Laravel 5.7 to Laravel 8 and now have problem with email verification.

**Error**
Call to a member function getKey() on null

Here is the verify function code i have in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerifiesEmails.php

```
 public function verify(Request $request)

    {

        if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {

            throw new AuthorizationException;

        }

        .......

    }
```

**$request->user() is returning null.**

Comment: Did you follow each of the upgrade guides? You have to do 5.7 to 6.x, then 6.x to 7.x, then 7.x to 8.x; you can't just directly upgrade from 5.7 to 8.x and expect everything to work...

Comment: Yeh I did the same

Comment: That means $request does not have user object. Check what gets returned by doing dd($request);